# Place absolutely positioned element at top of window using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, css, window, positioning, absolute

I need, in pure javascript, a method for placing an absolutely positioned element (it's absolutely positioned relative to the body) at the top of the WINDOW, and not the body.

It can not be fixed position, absolute only.  I'm currently using a bit of a hackish method doing this:

```
var timeOut;
function scrollToTop() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop!=0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop!=0){
        window.scrollBy(0,-50);
        timeOut=setTimeout('scrollToTop()',10);
    }
    else clearTimeout(timeOut);
}
```

and...

```
onclick="scrollToTop();return false"
```

... to bring up an absolutely positioned div.

Now, depending on where the user is on the page, I need the window to appear at the top of their browser window, rather than the top of the document.  I know how to do this in jQuery, but I can't think of a method in javascript.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to scroll the window, or to position the div?  You say that you know how to do it in jQuery, can you post your jQuery solution?

Comment: Just position the div to the top of the browser window.  And it would only do it once, rather than sticking into position.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?  Every time you click the button (which is fixed), a Product Menu Bar div is added at the top of the window.

http://jsfiddle.net/kmFQD/1

Code:

```
function insertAtTop()
{
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.innerHTML = "Product Menu Bar";
    newDiv.className = "productMenuBar";
    newDiv.style.top = pageYOffset + "px";

    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

Comment: I think we're on the right path here, but it's an element that is not added until the button is clicked.

Comment: My answer and JSFiddle have been edited to address the previous comment.